# How can find iframe which is DIV > Iframe > form > text field with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to target **email text field** inside form which resides in iframe .

```
<div class="iframecontainer">
    <div class="iframe">
      <div class="headerText resultHeader">Result:</div>
      <div class="iframewrapper">
        <iframe id="iframeResult" class="result_output" frameborder="0" name="view" xsrc="tryhtml_input_readonly.htm">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

    <form action="demo_form.asp">
         **Email**: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="footerText">Try it Yourself - &copy; <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a></div>      
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me to do it with Watir-webdriver

Comment: Have you tried using xpath? It searches based on the dom-tree. [xpath-tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Comment: You'll need to switch focus to the iframe window. Please search StackOverflow for answers and then show us your code if you're still having trouble.

Comment: @SayusiAndo 
I have been using this  @browser.frame(:id=> "iframeResult" ) to locate the frame , but it always it is returning me "false" . is there any way

Comment: @FDM : I am trying to find out that on stack-overflow , i did not get solution . can you please help me

Comment: I voted to close this question as unclear what you are asking, because without more information its not possible to answer this question. We also need the (ruby) code you are currently using to drive the watir-webdriver test.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access elements in frames you first need to switch to them.

Try to use `driver.switch_to.frame "iframeResult"` first and afterwards try to find or interact with the input elements.

Comment: This should really be a comment - you should either delete your answer and post this as a comment, or expand on your answer.